# Comparing user input to an array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, equals

I have to compare what a user types in to an array of names and if it's true it returns true otherwise it returns false so far i have this

```
public static boolean employeeReport(Employee[] emp, String[] lastName) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Type out the last name of the employee you are looking for: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    String Name = scan.next();

    // ...
}
```

I was thinking of making a for loop and comparing "Name" to each individual value of a String array i have. Any help?

Comment: Maybe you should mention the language you're using!?

Answer (score 0):

insert all the names of employees to

```
Set<String> set
```

and then just check

```
set.contains(name) //return true if exists and false if not
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an array of String with employee names, eg:

```
String[] nameBook;
```

you could do this:

```
public static boolean employeeReport(Employee[] emp, String[] lastName) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Type out the last name of the employee you are looking for: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    String name = scan.next();

    //loop through the array and compare against entered name
    for(String n : nameBook) {
        if (n.equals(name)) return true;
    }

    return false;  
}
```

Please note that by Java convention, variable names should start with lower case letter (I've corrected it in your code).